# Macbook Pro randomly waking up from Sleep Mode, on Kubuntu and many other distro

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, suspend, power-management, macbook-pro

My device is a MacBook Pro early 2015 edition, irrespective of the Linux distro when ever I put the laptop to sleep it wakes up immediately. I can't keep it in sleeping mode.
I have no idea where to start to troubleshoot this issue so please help!

Right now I am on Kubuntu 20.04. I don't use tlp, using it doesn't solve the problem as well. Tried Auto CPU config, nothing there too.

Where to start if I want to solve this issue?

Comment: Other OSes was on kernel 5.4 except for manjaro which used 5.6. Same issue everywhere.

Comment: I don't know if the issue is related to GNOME or KDE, that is why I mentioned it.

Comment: I found that disabling  "XHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0" in (/proc/acpi/wakeup) might help but can't do that because it gave this "Error writing lock file ./.wakeup.swp: No such file or directory".

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution...
Apparently the problem is XHC1 enabled in '/proc/acpi/wakeup'
To disable it using nano wont help so run the following as root

> ~# echo XHC1 >> /proc/acpi/wakeup

The problem is it needs to be done at every startup and after XHC1 is disabled only the power button can wake the system from sleep. Laptop lid does work though.

A more permanent solution is given in [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/3zxg65/how_to_permanently_change_procacpiwakeup_or/cypusck?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3); haven't tried it yet.

Comment: New day and this doesn't work.. Have no idea why it did work yesterday!

Comment: In another answer it's recommended to also disable LID0 (laptop lid) because of "glitchy behavior". Maybe that glitch is the reason it doesn't always work for you:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1203159/1135717

Comment: Disabling XHC1 and LID0 worked during ... months...

Now, it has no effect. I have still the bug even in disabling XHC1 and LID0

Anybody has another solution ?